# Scala, Collection.searching with user-defined implicit Ordering[]

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, search, implicit

I need to perform binary search on an array of custom case class. This should be as simple as calling the `search` function defined in `scala.collection.Searching`:

[image]

As you can see, if the collection on which I call the search method is an *indexed sequence*, the binary search is performed.

Now, I need to create my custom `Ordering[B]` parameter and I want to pass it explicitly to the `search` function (I don't want for it to take any implicit parameter inferred from context).

I have the following code:

```scala
// File 1
case class Person(name: String, id: Int)
object Person{ 
  val orderingById: Ordering[Person] = Ordering.by(e => e.id)
}

// File 2 (same package)
for(i <- orderedId.indices) {
  // orderedId is an array of Int
  // listings is an array of Person
  val listingIndex = listings.search(orderedId(i))(Person.orderingById)
  ...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Type mismatch. Required: Ordering[Any], found: Ordering[Nothing]

So, I tried change the implementation in this way:

```
// file 1
object Person{
  implicit def orderingById[A <: Person] : Ordering[A] = {
      Ordering.by(e => e.id)
  }
}
//file 2 as before
```

This time getting the following error:

> Type mismatch. Required: Ordering[Any], found: Ordering[Person]

Why does it happen? At least in the second case, should it convert from `Any` to `Person`?

Comment: What is the type of `listing` what is the type of `orderedId`?

Comment: `Listing` -> Array of `Person`, `orderedId` -> Array of `Int`. It is written as a comment in the code, but maybe it's not enough evident/visible.

Comment: You are searching in an array of persons an int, that will never work. You want this: `listings.find(p => p.id == orderedId(i))` and remove the custom ordering since it is not needed - Also, please, do not use **Arrays**, also please do not use an imperative loop, also please take a look to the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/). Also, if you are going to constantly search things by a key maybe it would be better to transform that into a **Map**-

Comment: igol, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the type specifications.

If you want to `.search()` on a collection of `Person` elements then the first `search` parameter should be a `Person` (or a super-class thereof).

```
val listingIndex =
  listings.search(Person("",orderedId(i)))(Person.orderingById)
```

Or, to put it in a more complete and succinct context:

```
import scala.collection.Searching.SearchResult

case class Person(name: String, id: Int)

val listings: Array[Person] = ...
val orderedId: Array[Int]   = ...

for(id <- orderedId) {
  val listingIndex: SearchResult =
    listings.search(Person("",id))(Ordering.by(_.id))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a bit just to elaborate about your error. First, please note that [`Searching.search`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Searching.scala#L55) is deprecated, with deprecation message:

> Search methods are defined directly on `SeqOps` and do not require `scala.collection.Searching` any more.

[`search`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.scala#L110) is now defined on [`IndexedSeqOps`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.scala#L35). Let's look at the signature:

```
final def search[B >: A](elem: B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B])
```

When you call:

```
listings.search(orderedId(i))(Person.orderingById)
```

The result of `orderedId(i)` is `Int`. Therefore, `B` in the signature above is `Int`. The definition of `Int` is:

```
final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal
```

`A` is `Person`, because `listing` is of type `Array[Person]`. Therefore, `search`, is looking for a common root for both `Int` and `Person`. This common root is `Any`, hence you are getting this error. One way to overcome it, is to define an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Person`:

```
object Person{
  val orderingById: Ordering[Person] = Ordering.by(e => e.id)

  implicit def apply(id: Int): Person = {
    Person("not defined", id)
  }
}
```

Then the following:

```
val listings = Array(Person("aa", 1), Person("bb", 2), Person("dd", 4))
val orderedId = 1.to(6).toArray

for(i <- orderedId.indices) {
  // orderedId is an array of Int
  // listings is an array of Person
  listings.search[Person](orderedId(i))(Person.orderingById) match {
    case Found(foundIndex) =>
      println("foundIndex: " + foundIndex)
    case InsertionPoint(insertionPoint) =>
      println("insertionPoint: " + insertionPoint)
  }
}
```

will produce:

```
foundIndex: 0
foundIndex: 1
insertionPoint: 2
foundIndex: 2
insertionPoint: 3
insertionPoint: 3
```

Code run in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/KtG50noZRR65oO2s5q1ePA).